# Camel K and Amazon EKS (Elastic Kubernetes Service)

Tags: apache-camel-k

I'm trying to deploy a simple camel-k configuration and make it work with Amazon EKS.
What I did:

1. created a new Kubernetes cluster based on Amazon EKS
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e060N.png)
2. installed Camel-K using the command

```
kamel install --registry docker.io --organization user_id --registry-secret pass
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HHBKS.png)
After this, I have a camel-k active pod
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zopst.png)
3. tried to run follow sample integration

```
// camel-k: language=java

    import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
    public class Demo extends RouteBuilder {
      @Override
      public void configure() throws Exception {
          // Write your routes here, for example:
          from("timer:java?period=1000")
            .routeId("java")
            .setBody()
              .simple("Hello Camel K from ${routeId}")
            .to("log:info");
      }
    }
```

using the command

```
kamel run Demo.java --dev
```

I have the next output after this command:

```
Progress: integration "demo" in phase Initialization
Progress: integration "demo" in phase Building Kit
Condition "IntegrationPlatformAvailable" is "True" for Integration demo: default/camel-k
Integration demo in phase "Initialization"
Integration demo in phase "Building Kit"
Condition "IntegrationKitAvailable" is "False" for Integration demo: creating a new integration kit
Integration demo subresource kit-c23tllgnm1jafvoms1t0 (Integration Kit) changed phase to "Build Submitted"
Integration demo subresource kit-c23tllgnm1jafvoms1t0 (Build) changed phase to "Scheduling"
Integration demo subresource kit-c23tllgnm1jafvoms1t0 (Build) changed phase to "Pending"
Integration demo subresource kit-c23tllgnm1jafvoms1t0 (Build) changed phase to "Running"
Integration demo subresource kit-c23tllgnm1jafvoms1t0 (Integration Kit) changed phase to "Build Running"
Integration demo subresource kit-c23tllgnm1jafvoms1t0 (Build) changed phase to "Failed"
Integration demo subresource kit-c23tllgnm1jafvoms1t0 (Build) changed phase to "Initialization" (recovery 1 of 5)
Integration demo subresource kit-c23tllgnm1jafvoms1t0 (Build) changed phase to "Scheduling" (recovery 1 of 5)
Integration demo subresource kit-c23tllgnm1jafvoms1t0 (Build) changed phase to "Pending" (recovery 1 of 5)
Integration demo subresource kit-c23tllgnm1jafvoms1t0 (Build) changed phase to "Running" (recovery 1 of 5)
Integration demo subresource kit-c23tllgnm1jafvoms1t0 (Build) changed phase to "Failed" (recovery 1 of 5)
(combined from similar events): Integration demo subresource kit-c23tllgnm1jafvoms1t0 (Build) changed phase to "Initialization" (recovery 2 of 5)
(combined from similar events): Integration demo subresource kit-c23tllgnm1jafvoms1t0 (Build) changed phase to "Scheduling" (recovery 2 of 5)
(combined from similar events): Integration demo subresource kit-c23tllgnm1jafvoms1t0 (Build) changed phase to "Pending" (recovery 2 of 5)
(combined from similar events): Integration demo subresource kit-c23tllgnm1jafvoms1t0 (Build) changed phase to "Running" (recovery 2 of 5)
(combined from similar events): Integration demo subresource kit-c23tllgnm1jafvoms1t0 (Build) changed phase to "Failed" (recovery 2 of 5)
(combined from similar events): Integration demo subresource kit-c23tllgnm1jafvoms1t0 (Build) changed phase to "Initialization" (recovery 3 of 5)
(combined from similar events): Integration demo subresource kit-c23tllgnm1jafvoms1t0 (Build) changed phase to "Scheduling" (recovery 3 of 5)
(combined from similar events): Integration demo subresource kit-c23tllgnm1jafvoms1t0 (Build) changed phase to "Pending" (recovery 3 of 5)
(combined from similar events): Integration demo subresource kit-c23tllgnm1jafvoms1t0 (Build) changed phase to "Running" (recovery 3 of 5)
(combined from similar events): Integration demo subresource kit-c23tllgnm1jafvoms1t0 (Build) changed phase to "Failed" (recovery 3 of 5)
(combined from similar events): Integration demo subresource kit-c23tllgnm1jafvoms1t0 (Build) changed phase to "Initialization" (recovery 4 of 5)
(combined from similar events): Integration demo subresource kit-c23tllgnm1jafvoms1t0 (Build) changed phase to "Scheduling" (recovery 4 of 5)
(combined from similar events): Integration demo subresource kit-c23tllgnm1jafvoms1t0 (Build) changed phase to "Pending" (recovery 4 of 5)
(combined from similar events): Integration demo subresource kit-c23tllgnm1jafvoms1t0 (Build) changed phase to "Running" (recovery 4 of 5)
(combined from similar events): Integration demo subresource kit-c23tllgnm1jafvoms1t0 (Build) changed phase to "Failed" (recovery 4 of 5)
(combined from similar events): Integration demo subresource kit-c23tllgnm1jafvoms1t0 (Build) changed phase to "Initialization" (recovery 5 of 5)
(combined from similar events): Integration demo subresource kit-c23tllgnm1jafvoms1t0 (Build) changed phase to "Scheduling" (recovery 5 of 5)
(combined from similar events): Integration demo subresource kit-c23tllgnm1jafvoms1t0 (Build) changed phase to "Failed" (recovery 5 of 5)
Integration demo subresource kit-c23tllgnm1jafvoms1t0 (Integration Kit) changed phase to "Error"
Progress: integration "demo" in phase Error
Error: integration "demo" deployment failed
```

I got camel pod (camel-k-operator-id) log but I could not find any information in the log that can help me to understand the real problem of this error.
Could someone please help how I can get the details of the error occurring?

And the main question is it possible to use Camel-K with Amazon Elastic Kubernetes Service?
I have not just found any information in the official documentation.

Answer (score 0):

the problem has been fixed, for more information please visit https://github.com/apache/camel-k/issues/2241